# Can't recover password without loggin in in MVC with Forms Authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web-config, forms-authentication

I use Forms Authentication on my project and need to implement the feature for password recovery. Problem is, every time I try to access another controller method I get redirected to the login page. I tried to use

```
  </location>
  <location path="~/Account/RecoverPassword">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

on the web.config, but didn't work. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`*` means any *existing* user.
You want `users="?"`, which means *anonymous* users.